# Append text to existing target cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a large data set based on tag numbers:

```
tag    | value 1 | value 2 | ...     | value 20| comment    |
------------------------------------------------------------
01     | data    | data    | data    | data    | red        |
02     | data    | data    | data    | data    | blue       |   
03     | data    | data    | data    | data    | purple     |
04     | data    | data    | data    | data    | green      |
04     | data    | data    | data    | data    | green      |
.
.
03     | data    | data    | data    | data    | purple     |
```

I would like to check the 'tag' column for duplicate values, and if found, append the word 'duplicate' to the comment, without using an extra column for the calculation. For the table above, the result would be:

```
tag    | value 1 | value 2 | ...     | value 20| comment            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
01     | data    | data    | data    | data    | red                |
02     | data    | data    | data    | data    | blue               |   
03     | data    | data    | data    | data    | purple             |
04     | data    | data    | data    | data    | green              |
04     | data    | data    | data    | data    | green - duplicate  |
.
.
03     | data    | data    | data    | data    | purple - duplicate |
```

Is this possible? If so, please provide an example.

Comment: I'm open to using VBA, but do not have much experience with it. I will add  the VBA tag to the question.

Comment: Added the request for an example - realized that with the word "Yes" @pnuts had completely answered the question as originally written. ;)

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA you can insert a column with the following formula `=IF(MAX(COUNTIF(A:A,A1))>1,"Duplicates"," ")` or `IF(MAX(COUNTIF($C$9:C18,$C$9:C18))>1,"Duplicates"," ") `

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu would this mark ALL instances of the dup, or everything after the first?

Comment: @KidAsComputer the first formula will flag all as duplicates and the second only those after the first appearance, just be sure to lock the first cell in the beginning of the list.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu had to modify it to this:  `=IF(MAX(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2))>1, "Duplicate"," ")` to get it to behave properly. it does use an extra column, but will do for now. Thanks.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu addendum to the comment above: tried using the `MAX(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2))>1` for conditional formatting over the range of the whole sheet (so that the entire row of a duplicate would be hightlighted) and made excel seize in a way I've never seen before - looked like fireworks!

Comment: @KidAsComputer, Fireworks = Good?? I use the formula to get duplicates in one of the sheets my company utilises. place the formula on the first cell of the range and then expand to the all range.  `=IF(MAX(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A$2:$A2))>1, "Duplicate"," ")`. Btw how big is you data set?

Comment: no, fireworks = BSOD. Data set is about 2500 rows x 30 columns. About half the are pulling data/calculating from 2 other sheets. w/ all the conditional formatting it's starting to bog down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is like:

[image]

Then this short macro should do it:

```
Sub DupFinder()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, i As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If wf.CountIf(Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(1, 1)), Cells(i, 1).Value) > 1 Then
            Cells(i, "V").Value = Cells(i, "V").Value & " Duplicate"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This assumes that the comment column is column **V**

Comment: Thanks I will implement this and let you know how it works - Will this run in the background (i.e. update as rows are added to the table? Also if the duplicate row is deleted, will the " Duplicate" be removed from the 'comment' column?

Comment: @KidAsComputer  The code could be modified to do both these functions.